# Protect private certificate from Mimikatz

Tags: windows, security, ssl-certificate, devops, client-certificates

Which is the best way to protect a private(client) certificate from Mimikatz on Windows? 
currently, my certificates mark as non-exportable, but when I run Mimikatz, it succeeds to export them.

Answer (score 0):

Enable LSA Protection on all Windows versions in the enterprise that supports it. This prevents Mimikatz from working “out-of-the-box” and requires use of the Mimikatz driver which logs events when it interacts with LSASS.

More information [here](https://adsecurity.org/?page_id=1821)